# How to merge all STL files to one geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

The code is as follows. I find it too troublesome. Is there a better way to do it? I do this for the overall export to a STL file, or to do the overall cutting function, thank you!

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color:0xffffff,
} );
loader.load( 'fanban1.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    stl_mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
    stl_mesh1.position.set(20, 0, 40);
    stl_mesh1.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    stl_mesh1.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    group.add(stl_mesh1);
    arr_mesh.push(stl_mesh1);
});


var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color:0xFFFF00,
} );
loader.load( 'fanban2.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    stl_mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
    stl_mesh2.position.set(20, 0, -20);
    stl_mesh2.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    stl_mesh2.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    group.add(stl_mesh2);
    arr_mesh.push(stl_mesh2);
});
scene.add(group);
```

Then,I edit it link this:

```
    var allGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    loader.load( 'fanban.stl', function ( geometry ) {
        stl_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        stl_mesh.position.set(20, 0, -60);
        stl_mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
        stl_mesh.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
        group.add(stl_mesh);
        arr_mesh.push(stl_mesh);
        allGeometry.merge(geometry);
    });
```

But report errors:THREE.Geometry.merge(): geometry not an instance of THREE.Geometry.

Comment: `.merge()` doesn't work because `THREE.STLLoader()` returns a non-indexed [`THREE.BufferGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferGeometry.merge). So, try to use `var allGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice，I try it  `var allGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();`,`allGeometry.merge(geometry);`,`var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( allGeometry, material );scene.add(mesh);`

Comment: You can look at my sample code here：[link](https://github.com/pandabajie/3d/blob/master/hgprinter/drag_model_001.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in terms of a code review? If so then it would be better to move your question [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If so, then they both do the same thing when the mesh is loaded so something like this would be a good start:

```
function constructMesh(geo, mat, x, y, z, scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
  mesh.scale.set(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
  group.add(mesh);
  arr_mesh.push(mesh);
}
```

Implemented like:

```
var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffffff}),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffff00})
];

loader.load( 'fanban1.stl', function ( geometry ) {
  constructMesh(geo, materials[0], 20, 0, 40, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);      
});
loader.load( 'fanban2.stl', function ( geometry ) {
  constructMesh(geo, materials[1], 20, 0, -20, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3); 
});
scene.add(group);
```

Comment: Thank you very much！But this is not the answer I want, and all the STL geometries I want to merge together into a geometric body.